# How to retain session after java web server redeployed or crashed

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, memcached

People usually use `SessionManager` to keep the *session variable* for each *web agent*. But these values will be lost if the server is crashed or redeployed.

I can think of some way such as save session to an external *memcached*, *database* or *file*, but I'm not sure which way is suitable to face with security problem and perform the best performance.

How can I keep sessions alive after restarting the service?

Comment: What are you using session for? Makes a lot of difference for security reasons!

Comment: I've edited your question to make it expressive, feel free to edit it if the question isn't accurate.

Comment: Most Java EE implementations (and Tomcat) provide configuration settings that manage this for you - no need to implement it yourself. RTFM